# I want to know how to select all data in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm creating a combined database using different tables.

But I don't know how to show a combined tables using `select * from` query without T-SQL in different tables.

Please, inform how to resolve  for problem as follows.

Database information:

- Database name : `Ex_database`
- Tables in database: `NH_2002, NH_2003, NH_2004, NH_2005, NH_2006, NH_2007, NH_2008, NH_2009, NH_2010, NH_2011, NH_2012, NH_2013`
- Columns included in all tables : `STND_Y, PERSON_ID, SEX, AGE_GROUP`

Expected result is as shown below

```
STND_Y  PERSON_ID  SEX  AGE_GROUP    
----------------------------------
2002    94079912    2   18  
2002    39293901    1   1       
2003    60050613    1   1       
2003    72362112    1   1       
2004    63794548    1   1       
2004    62816669    1   1       
2005    77409521    1   1       
2005    20379447    1   1       
2006    37892859    1   1       
2006    22648545    1   1   
2007    32432467    2   1
2007    83834242    1   1
2008    23423412    1   1
2008    34234234    2   1
2009    45348573    1   1
2009    34242342    1   1
2010    34123145    1   1
2010    34564563    2   1
2011    98776786    1   1
2011    65745634    1   1
2012    73847205    1   1
2012    87653039    2   1
2013    23423164    2   1
2013    42341242    2   1
```

Comment: It can be done with union but we don't know the content of every table. If he need `PERSON_ID` of each table or `it according with every STND_Y` The answer below is your first step.

Comment: If values are different then union will give the same result as union all automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much. I could solve the problem because of you.

Comment: Request you to kindly vote for my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from NH_2002
union all
select * from NH_2003
union all
select * from NH_2004
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I could solve the problem because of you

Answer (score 2):

The [`union all`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) syntax allows you to combine results from multiple queries into a single output.

```
SELECT STND_Y, PERSON_ID,  SEX,  AGE_GROUP
FROM NH_2002
UNION ALL
SELECT STND_Y, PERSON_ID,  SEX,  AGE_GROUP
FROM NH_2003
UNION ALL
SELECT STND_Y, PERSON_ID,  SEX,  AGE_GROUP
FROM NH_2004
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I could solve the problem because of you

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `UNION` or `UNION ALL` as shown below depending upon the requirement whether you need to keep duplicate values or not.

```
SELECT STND_Y, PERSON_ID, SEX, AGE_GROUP FROM NH_2002
UNION
SELECT STND_Y, PERSON_ID, SEX, AGE_GROUP FROM NH_2003
UNION
SELECT STND_Y, PERSON_ID, SEX, AGE_GROUP FROM NH_2004
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I could solve the problem because of you